# Anchor tag not working in gmail attachment

Tags: javascript, html, css

I  am using an anchor tag to go to specific section within the same page.This method is working when I have the html file in my local machine. But when I attach the file in gmail and open the attachment , it does not work.Why? What should I do in order to make it work?
BTW , is it possible to make it work on gmail attachment?

**P.S**: I am sick of this html incompatibility.

Comment: An anchor tag - a hashtag -  a part of the url - document.location.hash. Where in an email do you have an address bar ? Think about it ... - gmail will be opening the html in it's own preview most likely

Comment: Sounds like OP is trying to exploit the fact that some mail UAs render mime/multipart HTML attachments as HTML web page fragments -- and on that basis is attempting to apply general web application development methodologies (i.e: as if it were a web page served over HTTP to a modern web browser). False premise.

Comment: Please always include relevant code. Even though here what you ask for seems not possible.

Comment: Here's a blog article which goes into this subject in-depth:  http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3322/the-trouble-with-anchor-links-in-email-newsletters

Answer (score 1):

You can't use typical HREF anchors to navigate between elements on the same page in Gmail because Gmail modifies all of the HREF values within an email once it's received by the server.  For example, in the screenshot attached, notice the anchor tag.. the original code ended with JMIA.  Everything after that was appended by Gmail.

[image]

You can however use this alternative syntax and it will work, but is limited to whether or not the element being navigated to is visible within the reading pane.  If the element is already visible on the screen, Gmail will not scroll down to it.

```
<a name="..">
```